# Fourier expansion and transform - what about the phase of the waves that i am adding?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, transformation

Say we have a wave on the surface of the water and we want to describe it as a sum of other waves. So we use Fourier expansion to add waves of different wavelengths. For simplicity, say we have to just add two waves in order to get the mathematical description of the wave we have. If we add the two waves, the resulting wave will largely depend on the phase difference of the waves we added. For example, if the two waves are sinusoidal , if they have zero phase difference they will add up to a different wave than if they had a phase difference of π
So, how do we consider the phase of each wave that we add up in the Fourier expansion and Fourier transform?

Comment: The FT of a real wave form is complex and the ratio of the components at a given frequency encodes the phase at that frequency.

Comment: Yes, but why it makes a difference in which phase we add a wave in FT. In physics it makes a great difference. So why do we just choose to add waves of different wavelengths without choosing their individual phases?

Comment: We don't, in terms of real valued waves, we add a pair of one in phase and the other in quadrature (or sin and cosine waves if you will) which gives the phase.

Answer (score 0):

In Fourier analysis, we mostly do not use $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions, but instead use $e^{i\xi x}$.

The two approaches are equivalent, but with the complex exponentials, we have a huge advantage: If we change the phase (I.e. if we translate), we get $e^{i\xi (x+x_0)}=e^{i \xi x_0} e^{i \xi x}$, i.e. translation/change of phase corresponds to multiplying with a complex number of modulus 1 (a phase factor). Thus, the different phases can be encoded in the different coefficients of the individual "waves".

This behaviour is one of the main points of Fourier analysis, since it implies that translation invariant operators (convolution, differentiation) are diagonalised by the Fourier transform.

Comment: ξ here is the frequency and x is the phase?

Comment: @LandosAdam: I am sorry. With the physical interpretation, $\xi$ is the frequency, $x=t$ is time and $x_0=t_0$ is the phase/delay (time shift).

Comment: but in the Fourier transform we add waves of different ξ but all at time t. We do not add waves with different ξ AND t.

Comment: @LandosAdam: I thought you were asking what happens for e.g. $\sum a_n e^{i \xi_n (t + t_n)}$, i.e., you add waves with varying frequencies and phases (the phases come from the "$+t_n$"). Otherwise, what do you mean by the phase of a wave?

Comment: but the integral(or the sum as you put it) , sums up waves of different ξ(only one sum as you wrote yourself). It adds all the waves at the same phase.I mean, tn does not change for each wave that we sum up.